# Is it possible to automate an action at a certain interval in a tezos smart contract?

Tags: smart-contracts

Do you know a design who allow to automate an action at a certain interval ? (for example, call another contract every 20 blocks or something like that).

Thanks every one for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Contracts themselves don't have scheduling ability. You can set up a simple crontab job on your server to call tezos-client and execute the contract on whatever schedule you like.